# Adressing : "It is about 200 meters ahead/further"

Tags: word-choice

Please help me to address a shop in further distance.

> **A:** Hi, Where is the X shop?
>
> **B:** You are close, It's about 200 meters *ahead/further* (from here).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say "it's about .... further down (the street)".

Comment: "Further ahead" could also be an option.

Comment: It's two hundred meters from here. Why you need further? From here works. If you both have come from the same direction, just two hundred meters more will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of situation probably needs some inference in order for the asker to understand the answer.

"Ahead, further on, on, further" are all valid options if you **are referring to the path the asker is currently taking**, since they all imply "more"/"continuing as you are".

In the event that you **can't direct the asker in that manner**, then your suggestions aren't so good, and you would need to be more specific in your response:

> You're close. It's about 200 metres *that way* ****points in the appropriate direction****

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you JMB. It was very instructive. Let me elaborate a bit. I and asker and also that shop are all in the same street so if I want to address that shop I think all of your suggestions should be appropriate for addressing.

Comment: Though I'm not sure I understand your comment fully, I'd give you the general advice that the greater the context, the less specific you need to be with your prepositions/directions.